# Limit as $x$ approaches to $0$ is nonzero divided by $0$

Tags: calculus, limits

The equation I am dealing with is:

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2+3x}{3x^5}$$

First I tried to use L'Hopital's Rule but I got stuck with an equation $\frac{2x+3}{15x^4}$.
Another approach to this equation was to cancel $x$: $\frac{x+3}{3x^4}$, but it also gives nothing.

The right answer is $0$.

Comment: $\dfrac{x^2+3x}{3x^5}=\dfrac{1}{3x^3}+\dfrac{1}{x^4}\to......?$

Comment: @Piquito In that case it seems we obtain $-\infty+\infty$ when $x\to 0^-$.

Comment: The answer would be $0$ if the limit were taken as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @gimusi: Yes but the greater degree $4$ it is imposed.  We can put $$\dfrac{1}{x^3}\left(\dfrac 13+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$$. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Now I've solved my doubt about it. Thanks a lot for that clarification. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that following your way

$$2x+3\to 3$$

$$15x^4\to 0^+$$

therefore

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2+3x}{3x^5}\stackrel{H.R.}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x+3}{15x^4}=+\infty$$

Note also that we don't need l'Hopital indeed we can simply cancel out a $x$ factor from numerator and denominator to obtain

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2+3x}{3x^5}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x+3}{3x^4}=+\infty$$

indeed $x+3\to 3$ and $3x^4\to 0^+$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for clarification

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 3):

*Why* did you get stuck when you got $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x+3}{15x^4}$? This limit is equal to $+\infty$. Therefore, the limit that you're after is $+\infty$ too.

Comment: Thank you a lot now I get it. I just could not get how it is 0. I guess the answer is not correct or sth...